# Add New Line Transpose Info

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up an excel spreadsheet so that Sheet 2 Cell U2 is my control. If U3 doesn't match I want to add a row on sheet 1 between lines 2 and 3 and fill sheet 1 cell I3 (the New line) with the info from Sheet 2 cell D31. I actually need to do this with several cells, but if you can get me started I can finish the rest.

```html
Sub Test()

If Sheets("1").Range("D28") <> Sheets("1").Range("I26") Then
End If
If Sheets("1").Range("E28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("E28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("E27").Value
End If
If Sheets("1").Range("F28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("F28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("F27").Value
End If
If Sheets("1").Range("G28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("G28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("G27").Value
End If
If Sheets("1").Range("H28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("H28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("H27").Value
End If
If Sheets("1").Range("I28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("I28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("I27").Value
End If
If Sheets("1").Range("J28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("J28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("J27").Value
    End If
If Sheets("1").Range("K28").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Month").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Month").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("K28").Value
    Sheets("Month").Range("X3").Value = Sheets("1").Range("K27").Value
End If

End Sub
```

I have it almost complete, but i'm stuck. This is my code so far:What i'm having trouble with now, is I am getting multiple versions of the one line. I need it so if Sheets("1").Range("D28") <> Sheets("1").Range("I26") then it DOESN'T add the line for that match.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, this code would do the required task.

```
sub test()

If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("U3").Value <> Sheets("Sheet2").Range("U2").Value then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D31").Value
end If

end sub
```

However, since the question you are asking seems relatively simple, I'm assuming that you are relatively new to Excel VBA. I would then suggest you, for next time, to experiment a little bit with the **Record Macro** button available in the [Developper Tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45). Then look at the code you obtain to have some inspirations.

And for things that can't be recorded, such as **If-statements** or **For-loops**, then I would recommend searching online for some tutorials since you won't be able to really automate any tasks without those tools.

In fact, you mentioned that you might need to do this process for a few different cells which means that a **For-loop** could be handy to go through all the different cells that you need.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Happy coding!